# Update statement not affecting sqlite table

Tags: python, sqlite

I am a noob with sqlite.

I have created an sqlite database with a table called nutrients using python (see structure in the screen shot).

[image: Screen shot of nutrients table]

I have populated the table using

```
INSERT INTO nutrients ...
```

However I don't seem to be able to update a row. The following code

```
import sqlite3

path = 'nutrition.sqlite'

command = 'SELECT user_name FROM nutrients WHERE code="ALCO"'
connection = sqlite3.connect(path)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(command)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
print('before update', rows[0])

command = 'UPDATE nutrients SET user_name="Booze" WHERE code="ALCO"'
connection = sqlite3.connect(path)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(command)
cursor.close()
connection.close()

command = 'SELECT user_name FROM nutrients WHERE code="ALCO"'
connection = sqlite3.connect(path)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(command)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
print('after update', rows[0])
```

produces the output

```
('before update', (u'Alcohol',))
('after update', (u'Alcohol',))
```

Comment: You need `cursor.commit()` after executing the `UPDATE`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. I took your advice, but it is actually connection.commit() that I needed ;)

Comment: Interestingly, the sqlite tutorial here http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/update/ does not mention commit!!!

Comment: It's not a sqlite thing, it's part of the Python cursor implementation.

Comment: @Barmar Yes. But the tutorial is a Python tutorial. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure why the tutorial is missing that. Minor correction, it should be `connection.commit()`. See https://pysqlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit